# Where should I place code that must be run before a form is saved?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, devforce

I have VM which controls what displayed, etc. In my case - it's User editing screen.

I have some code where before user saved - I take entered password, encrypt it with salt and stuff into entity property.

So, where this code belongs? Right now I'm intercepting OnBeforeSave and put it there. Should I move it to the model?

EDIT:

More info on my environment/layers:

1. Silverlight
2. Views (XAML)
3. ViewModel (encapsulates data access via repositories). Exposes properties and data objects to bind
4. Model - DevForce framework responsivle for persistance. I also use it's validation functionality. I can extend it with partial classes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a perfect example of business logic: it doesn't belong in the model, it belongs in whatever takes the model and passes it to the DAL, or repository, for instance.

If you can post some more info about the layers, or IoC-style services your app uses, we can probably be more specific.

(MVVM is about models, view models and views.. this isn't really much to do with MVVM in fact!)

Hope that helps.

(Edit: ohai it's you again, saw another question earlier today :) I'm not stalking you..)

Comment: I added more info. I'm not ohai :) 
Repository in my case is dependency injected wrapper to do CRUD